# How to create a custom nft collection from a web3 frontend

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ethereumjs, nft

I am currently working on an NFT marketplace and although currently users can mint nfts and list them on the marketplace, All NFTs are minted under the defult NFT contract i.e

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    address contractAddress;

    constructor(address marketplaceAddress) ERC721("MyCollectible", "MYC"){
        contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    }

    function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint){
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

But would like for them to be able to create their own collections with unique addresses from a input form on the frontend, Like with rarible custom collections or the mintable store. So my question is after they submit the dteails, how do I go about this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use something like [EIP-1167 - Minimal Proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167).

Comment: @Ismael I have been studying the concept of contract factories, proxies and initializers. But the question I cant seem to answer is, what do I make the implentation contract? The NFT contract above or the NFTMarket contract?

Comment: The minimal proxy pattern is usually used by factory contracts, that have to create the same child contract multiple times. Instead there will be one deployment of the full contract and the factory will deploy a small proxy that points to the full implementation saving gas.

Comment: If it is more convenient a single NFT contract or one per user, probably it is something you have to decide, perhaps provide both options to the user: 1/ sharing one contract will be cheaper but they will have less control, 2/ having their own contract will be more expensive but they will have more control.

Comment: A proxy just forwards all calls to another contract. OpenZeppelin has implementations for several NFT tokens, EIP-721, EIP-1155.